# new overview icon bottom left

Tags: gnome

I just noticed a new icon bottom/left on my screen (Ubuntu 22.04). Clicking it switches to some kind of overview mode that is virtually impossible to get out of. What is this? Any info and help on how to get rid of this icon is greatly appreciated :) I don't use any overview modes, and the dock/dash/whatever is never displayed here (disliked it from its first appearance ;) )
Here is the new icon:[image]

Comment: is the icon in the question appearing as a part of the dash/dock icon or bottom left? can you put a picture in that manner and also did you notice that after any accidental key pressings this came into action?

Comment: @UnKNOWn – wish I could answer that question. After a logout/login the icon has now disappeared! It was always bottom left on the screen, and – as I said – I have completely hidden the useless dash/dock. The icon looked like it was part of the window list extension.

Comment: I have tried this extension in Arch Linux. I Could not reproduce this. If you disable this extension for some time and then once you enable it if the same thing happens, then you can raise an issue with the GitHub link provided on the extension main page.

Comment: @UnKNOWn The icon reappeared today. Don't know what caused it, but by simply disabling/enabling the Window List extension it is now gone. I can live with that..!